# Select/Unselect collections through python script

Tags: python, scripting

I am new to blender, I have a bunch of collections say parent collections ( each collection has one or more sub collection say child collection)

What I want is , I want to select only one of the child collection for all parent collection and render it and save.
Ofcourse I want to unselect those collections for next render

I am unable to write the code to select/unselect child collection, tried linking bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collection)/ bpy.context.scene.collection.children.unlink(collection)

working fine for the first render but not working for many renders

wondering if there is a simple way to achive this

attached the image where parent and sub collections[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easier to disable and enable collections on render.

For example:

```
import bpy

for parent in bpy.context.scene.collection.children:
    for child in parent.children:

        # Lets enable collection with "1" in the name
        # You can define any other logic if you want
        if child.name.find('1')!=-1:
            child.hide_render = False
        else:
            child.hide_render = True
```

Or example with random:

```
import bpy
import random

for parent in bpy.context.scene.collection.children:

    # Disable all collections:
    for child in parent.children:
        child.hide_render = True

    # and enable back one random collection
    index = random.randint(0, len(parent.children)-1)
    parent.children[index].hide_render = False
```

[image]

You can also hide in viewport by using `hide_viewport`

If you want to use **Exclude** option to hide objects you should look into `view_layer` instead of `scene`:

```
import bpy
import random

for parent in bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children:

    # Disable all collections:
    for child in parent.children:
        child.exclude = True

    # and enable back one random collection
    index = random.randint(0, len(parent.children)-1)
    parent.children[index].exclude = False
```

[image]

Comment: Yes hide render , viewport fine, but actually the checkbox is what I want, 

say in a child collection there are 2 objects, those wont be enabled unless the checkbox of that child collection is ticked or selected

Comment: can you add some objects in child collection and make it selectable the whole child collection?

Comment: Agree, checkbox should be active. It controls trough View layer, so it is easier to use hide render in Python

Comment: I didn't catch that. Do you want to set "hide_select"?

Comment: Yeah I tried the hide_select, not working 

here is how I tried

I have a coll name = "sample"
col = bpy.data.collection['sample']
col.hide_select = False

Comment: If you want to block collection's objects from selecting, you should set `hide_select`  to `True`.

Comment: based on my understanding, hide_something is true means disable, hide_something is False means enable

so for the collection I set hide_select = False (to select), anyway I tried both values , nothing happend, I am using blender 3.0,, is that depreciated or something?

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to block selection. What are you trying to achive?

Comment: well, lets take your screenshot above for eg, take collection2 , and add few simple cube objects to each sub collection (2 1, 2 2, 2 3 2 4)

now I want to select the sub collection 2 2 only and render it ( means all the objects in the sub collection 2 2 only will be selected and rendered)

can you achive that from your example?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Yup that "exclude" I wanted, its working now

Thank you so much for your comments and answer